# Canon ts3100 won't scan but will print

Tags: linux-mint, usb, scanner, canon

I have recently changed from Windows and love using Linux. Lots of challenges but a great system. I have Mint 19.3 running 64 bit.  My printer/scanner is a Canon TS 3120, connected by usb to my computer. It prints fine but does not see the scanner. I am trying to use simple scan but it does not work.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be no SANE drivers for your model, but Canon offers a software called Scangear MP as Debian package compatible to your Mint on their support site:
https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/ts-series-inkjet/pixma-ts3120-black-wireless-all-in-one-inkjet-printer/pixma-ts3120?tab=drivers_downloads
Install that as root and you should be good to go.